# html email - no text displayed in iOS

Tags: ios, html-email, custom-font

I'm using custom font in html email but no text is displayed in iOS devices - it seems the text is transparent (you can copy/paste it).  All other devices are OK.

My code:

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'The Font'; 
        src: url("http://example.net/released-emails/new_template/thefont.ttf") format('truetype'), 
             url("http://example.net/released-emails/new_template/thefont.eot") format('eot'),
             url("http://example.net/released-emails/new_template/thefont.woff") format('woff');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal; 
            }

 body, p, a, span, strong {
               font-family: 'The Font', Verdana, sans-serif !important;
            }
```

**EDIT:**
I removed eot and woff. And with ttf alone, it works without problems.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with this code sample.